# Node app accessible inside aws server but not outside

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2

I am able to access my app inside the ec2 instance using elinks but when I try to do from the browser it says "This site can’t be reached".

I am trying to run a node app on port 3000

my netstat
[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6a3g.png)

[my ec2 security group inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ8jK.png)

Answer (score 0):

after going through other stackoverflow tickets I figured that there are two levels of checks

1. EC2 security groups
2. EC2 instance firewall

so although I added the port `3000` on security group inbound rules still I had to puncture the instance firewall as well. Port 80 is open by default

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually doing the same thing, and in order to do so, you need to give it a public IPv4 address and also run a web server from it. At least that is the conclusion I reached this morning.